# Unable to capture request from jQuery/Ajax by using 'term' in Django (backend)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jquery-mobile, django-views

I am unable to capture Ajax request by using `term` in Django (backend). I'm unsure if `term` is the right parameter to do this. Can some one suggest where I am going wrong.

Here is my Django code in views.py where I use `term`

```
def get_names(request):
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    names = Names.objects.filter(names__startswith=q)[:10]
    results = []
    if names.count > 0:
        for name in names:
            name_json = {}
            name_json['id'] = name.id
            name_json['label'] = name.name
            name_json['value'] = name.name
            results.append(name_json)
            data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
             data = 'fail'

    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Here is my jQuery mobile code

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.ajax({
                url: "/get_names/",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    q: $input.val()
                }
            })
            .then( function ( response ) {
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                $ul.html( html );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my html code

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">

    <div data-role="content">

    <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search House Id..." data-filter-theme="d"></ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the data as "q" in your js and then you attempt to access it by reading "term".

You should change this:

```
data: {
    q: $input.val()
}
```

to:

```
data: {
    term: $input.val()
}
```

I don't know if that's the only problem, but it's a good place to start for sure!

Comment: Thank you, I think it's working, need to resolve errors in my backend code.